# What are the minimum axioms required to prove Cantor's theorem? Is Extensionality + Power Set + $\Delta_0$-separation enough?

Tags: set-theory

Wikipedia says at most 5 axioms of power set, separation (of course a schema), extensionality, pairing, and infinity are needed, but to me it looks like we only need the first three.

Define $|A| \leq |B|$ as “there exists a bijection from $A$ onto a subclass of $B$”, which I'm pretty sure is equivalent to saying there's an injection. Define $|A| < |B|$ as $|A| \leq |B|$ and $|B| \nleq |A|$ (since we don't necessarily have $|{\leq}|$ antisymmetric).

The axiom of infinity isn't even needed, since the theorem has nothing to do with infinite sets specifically (that's the beautiful thing), and it would apply just as well to any smaller (Dedekind-finite) infinite set as to $\omega$, so singling out that specifically seems kind of arbitrary. Anyway, here's my argument:

(1) The converse partition principle (or maybe “converse axiom of choice”) states that: if $\exists a \in A$, for every injection $f:A \hookrightarrow B$ there is a left inverse $g:B \twoheadrightarrow A$ (proof: define $g(x) = \operatorname{Im}^{-1}_{f}(x)$ if it exists and $g(x) = a$ otherwise.)

Then we have the usual diagonalization: for any $S$, suppose there is a surjection $f:S \twoheadrightarrow \mathcal{P}(S)$. By separation the subset $D = \{s \in S \mid s \notin \operatorname{Im}_f(s)\}$ of $S$ exists, and $D \in \mathcal{P}(S)$, so there must be $s \in S$ so that $f(s) = D$. But $s \in D \iff s \notin \operatorname{Im}_f(s)$, and since both can't contain $s$, $\operatorname{Im}_f(s) \neq D$. No surjection can exist, so there is no injection from the nonempty $\mathcal{P}(S) \hookrightarrow S$.

(2) For any $S$, $S \subseteq S$, so $S \in \mathcal{P}(S)$. By applying separation to $\mathcal{P}(S)$, the singleton $\{S\}$ exists for every set $S$. Given any set $S$, then, there is an obvious injection into its power set, $f:S \hookrightarrow \mathcal{P}(S)$, $f:x \mapsto \{x\}$.

(1) and (2) suffice to show $|S| < |\mathcal{P}(S)|$. I also believe this only requires $\Delta_0$-separation, but I have trouble understanding how the Levy hierarchy for formulas works. Is my argument correct or did I make a leap somewhere (it feels “too convenient” so I feel like I might have)? Can this be made to work even without extensionality or reduced even further? Are there other choices of axioms very different from the ones I used but also very restricted that can prove it?

Comment: It is correct that infinity is not needed (unless one wants to show Cantor specifically for $\omega$ without the statement being potentially void). I suppose you need pairing in order to have functions *as sets*

Comment: Oh, that makes sense, actually. I completely overlooked having to deal with functions as actual sets to have things go through...

Comment: For proving $|S|\leq|\mathcal P(S)|$ it seems to me that you also need the axiom of unions, for making sure $S\times \mathcal P(S)$ exists, before you begin selecting from its power set. All of the _elements_ of $S\times\mathcal P(S)$ will exist thanks to pairing, but how do we know there's a set of them?

Comment: @Henning: I don't understand your last sentence in your last comment.

Comment: @Henning: Yes, of course. I just don't follow entirely the "transitively contain such atoms at two different depths" part.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: In retrospect that description was rather confusedly phrased (in particular because a Quine atom contains _itself_ at all possible depths ...)

Comment: .... actually that means my construction won't work as written. We need to consider a set that $S$ consists of something more interesting than Quine atoms.

Comment: @Henning: ah, thank you! I'd wondered if it could've been possible for non-wellfoundedness to cause problems but I couldn't imagine such an example (and it's still a bit hard to wrap my head around that one...)

Comment: @penguin_surprise: I don't think it's really well-foundedness that creates problems, but the details elude me at present. I will write an answer if I come up with a more watertight argument.

Comment: @I await your answer if you can think of it, then ^^! Re the first issue, does asserting binary unions of any $a,b$ suffice (which also covers pairing)? Ordered pairs from $S \times \mathcal{P}(S)$ should be in the 2nd power set of $S \cup \mathcal{P}(S)$, and that second power set should have $S \times \mathcal{P}(S)$ as a subset, I think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can explicitly construct a model of **{extensionality, pairing, separation, powerset, regularity}** where Cantor's Theorem fails in the sense that there is an $X$ that does not inject into its power set. The construction proceeds in a sequence of disjoint generations:

- First, the **red generation** $\mathbf R$, consists of all hereditarily finite sets of the ambient universe.
- Next, the **yellow generation** consists of infinitely many sets $(Y_n)_{n\in\mathbb Z}$ such that $Y_n=\{Y_{n+1}\}$.
- There are $\omega$ many **green generations**. The first of them, $\mathbf G_0$, consists of all sets of the form $\{\varnothing, Y_n\}$.

  Subsequentely, $\mathbf G_{n+1}$ consists of all subsets of $\mathbf R\cup\mathbf G_n$ that contain at least one element from $\mathbf G_n$ . Note that elements from *earlier* green generations are not allowed, and that $\mathbf G_n$ is itself an element of $\mathbf G_{n+1}$.
- Finally there are $\omega$ many **blue generations** which each consists of all the *finite* sets of elements from any earlier generations that have not themselves been added yet.

The union of all the generations is the claimed model.

- It satisfies *extensionality* by construction.
- It satisfies *pairing*, because every $x,y$ in the model will have their $\{x,y\}$ added in one of the blue generations if it didn't arise earlier.
- It has *all subsets* of every set. For a finite set, all its subsets will also be finite, so they are added in one of the blue generations at the latest. The only generations that can contain infinite sets are the green ones, and every subset of a green set is either red or in the same green generation.
- It has *power sets* of everything. Any *finite* set will have a finite power set, which will be added in one of the blue generations at latest. An infinite set from a green generation will have its power set in the next green generation.
- It satisfies *regularity*: Every descending $\in$-chain will eventually end in a tail of $Y_n$s (because all other generations add sets with members from earlier generations only), but there is never any *infinite* set that contains an $Y_n$.

Finally, $\mathbf G_0$ is in the model, but the model contains no injective map $f : \mathbf G_0\to\mathcal P(\mathbf G_0)$. Such a map would need to map some $g\in\mathbf G_0$ to a nonempty $h\subseteq \mathbf G_0$. However $h$ is in $\mathbf G_1$, which means that none of the green generations is allowed to contain $\{g,h\}$. This means that $\{g, h\}$ and the Kuratowski pair $\langle g, X\rangle$ are both blue -- but this means that every set that contains $\langle g,h\rangle$ is finite and so cannot be $f$.

---

The basic idea here is that for any *infinite* set, all $\in$-chains from it to a $\mathbf G_0$ set have the same length. I have not found a way to make that idea work with an *externally* well-founded model -- but of course that doesn't prove that there *can't* be well-founded models that fail Cantor's theorem.

---

Having a axiom of *binary unions* (rather than the full axiom of union), plus pairing, power set, and $\Delta_0$ separation (with parameters) would be enough to construct $X\times \mathcal P(X)$ and thence its power set and the injection $x\in X\mapsto \{x\}$.

Comment: This is being a bit improper. Formally speaking, Cantor's theorem states "There is no surjection from a set onto its power set". The injection in the other direction is "an obvious addition". Moreover, you discount the ability to perhaps define ordered pairs in a different way. Without Replacement you can't argue moving from one coding to another in an off-hand manner, so there might be a way to encode functions into your model still.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: My impression was that the OP wanted to prove $|S|<|\mathcal P(S)|$ using his definition at the top of the question, even though it might be debatable whether that _precise_ claim is what deserves to be called "Cantor's theorem". Of course, once we start questioning basic axioms such as pairing or union, much of the machinery we usually have in mind when judging different phrasings of definitions and theorems to be "clearly equivalent" falls apart, so where to attach the familiar names becomes a matter of taste and/or accident.

Comment: In any case, for discussing "which usual axioms can we omit and still prove such-and-such", it is necessary for such-and-such to be some very concrete fixed formula, and I don't think it is improper to assume for this purpose that the various concepts abbreviate the same things (such as Kuratowski pairs) they did _before_ we started stripping away axioms.

Comment: Yes, I agree with the first comment. Although I would perhaps advise to clarify that Cantor's theorem fails *in the sense that there is ...* rather than "because", since now we moved to the realm of "this theorem now has several interpretations".

Comment: @AsafKaragila: That's fair, edited.

Comment: @Henning Yeah, that was why I split it into two parts; I meant it to be a little more open-ended (in particular I wondered if (1) aka Cantor's theorem proper could be proved "more easily" than (2) which is usually automatic. I definitely agree that as you strip away axioms equivalent things will be non-equivalent

Comment: What you're talking about (Cantor's theorem holds, but there's no injection to the power set) was actually one of the things I was wondering. I think it's a good example and it shows that Cantor's theorem "fails in a sense" though I agree with @Asaf - I tend to think of ordered pairs / products as having many possible constructions. I be more convinced (but not surprised!) if there's no construction of $(a,b)$ that exists for all a, b and allows constructing functions and products for all pairs of sets.

Comment: To construct just $S \times \mathcal{P}(S)$ with *some* relatively "reasonable" definition of ordered pair like $ (a, b)$ = $ \{ \{ \{ a \} \}, \{ \{ a \},b\}\}$ or $\{\{\{a\}, 0\},\{b\}\}$, I think will still work even without pairing or union $\{a,b\}$ and prove the injection and lack of a surjection $S \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(S)$ and the lack of an injection in reverse, if only for the special case of a set and its powerset. "In that sense" it holds, though lacking functions it probably doesn't make sense to meaningfully talk about "cardinality."

Comment: @penguin_surprise: The specialized pairs with $a$ and $b$ at different depths you propose there would work fine in full set theory -- but in my model, with union removed, they'd end up concluding that $S$ now doesn't inject into _itself_! In order to achieve $|S|\le|\mathcal P^n(S)|$ for all $n$, it seems you would need to redefine $|A|\le|B|$ along the lines of "$|A|\le|B|$ iff there is any notion of (ordered) pair such that ..." but I don't think that can be done while staying first-order.

Comment: @Henning Markholm: !!!!! Okay, good, that actually answers *exactly* one of the things I was wondering from the start - whether we can prove could there still be some $n > m$ in the sequence of iterated power sets of S so that $|\mathcal{P}^n(S)|$ injects into $|\mathcal{P}^m(S)|$ or there's a surjection in reverse.

Comment: I agree the formulation in terms of $\leq$ wouldn't keep making sense there; you at least need binary unions and to construct all binary products and functions; and beyond iterated powersets it most certainly can't work for all sets. I get what you're saying about "$≤$ iff there exists a suitable notion"… you're probably right, but I see it more as "this theory is too weak to meaningfully talk about functions and their existence and cardinality in general" (it would need products) yet is still capable of (arguably) showing something in this one instance

Comment: @Henning Anyway I'm convinced by your answer/comments and others that the "real" minimum requires binary unions and pairs (though I'd just state union as there being $X \cup Y$, not $\bigcup S$ for 2-element $S$, to cover that) and trying to prove a variation like this without them is kind of a silly hack if anything because way too much breaks down.